# Implementing my own voice in a chatbot

Tags: voice, chatbot

I would like to have my own voice respond to me true a chatbot.
I have found a lot of tutorials on chatbot's. just non of them tell me how to intergrade my own voice. 
Someone with tips?

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.quora.com/How-do-people-make-computer-voices-like-Siri-or-Google-Now/answer/Marcus-L-Endicott

I've answered a question on Quora about this, including links to videos about Susan Bennett and Roger Ebert.